# Using Javascript I need to search URLs for file extensions, but it's not including the period in my search

Tags: javascript, search

Here's an example: `if( url.search(".png") != -1 || url.search(".jpg") != -1 || url.search(".jpeg") != -1 || url.search(".tif") != -1 || url.search(".tiff") != -1){`

If the url contains just "png" or "jpg" it'll return true. How do I check to make sure the "." is in there as well / why is it ignoring the period?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#search`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.search) expects a regular expression to search for matches for, not a simple string. In a regular expression `.` means "any character".

Use [`String#indexOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.indexof) instead of `search` for what you're doing. It uses simple string matching.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var url = "converted-from-png.jpeg";
snippet.log("search('.png'): " + url.search(".png") + " <== Wrong!");
snippet.log("indexOf('.png'): " + url.indexOf(".png"));
snippet.log("search('.jpeg'): " + url.search(".jpeg") + " <== Right, but would be wrong in other strings");
snippet.log("indexOf('.jpeg'): " + url.indexOf(".jpeg"));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! And I learned something new today :)